# Upgrade Drupal 7 to Drupal 9

Tags: upgrade, drupal-8, drupal-9

I am upgrading Drupal 7 to Drupal 9 and trying to copy over my CiviCRM database.

My Drupal 9 install is fresh.  I used the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/ to download CiviCRM with Composer.

I have upgraded the existing CiviCRM settings file to work with Drupal 9.

The problem is that I am getting the following error when trying to load Drupal."Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 516 of                                           /home/user/public_html/web/sites/default/civicrm."

As expected Drupal will not load at all.

I have checked all my paths and that CiviCRM is in my vendor folder.  /home/user/public_html/vendor/civicrm

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3):

Have you updated the civicrm.settings.php to include new location for $civicrm_root?

Add below entries in your civicrm.settings.php

```
$civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . '/libraries/civicrm/';                                                                                                     
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . '/libraries/civicrm/';
$civicrm_setting['domain']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . '/libraries/civicrm/';
$civicrm_paths['cms.root']['path'] = '/home/path-to-drupal9/web';
```

Comment: That was the problem.  However, I got it installed now and civicrm gets a 404 now that it is installed.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! The issue with the 404 is that there was old advice to use Minimal Drupal install. However, the minimal install does not have the path module so /civicrm is not a valid path.