# Migrating drupal 7 civicrm webforms to drupal 9 civicrm webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm, migration

What is the best way of approaching this such that I can avoid having to rebuild the forms manually - especially if I have a lot of forms.

Answer (score 1):

If only a couple of forms then it may be simpler to just rebuild but if you want to migrate you could look at using https://github.com/fuzionnz/webform_civicrm_migrate and https://github.com/fuzionnz/webform_migrate_plus.

Both modules are under ongoing refinements - definitely backup before using.

(for more about migrating civicrm from d7 to d9 read: [Moving existing CiviCRM to new Drupal instance + upgrade to Drupal 9](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40851/moving-existing-civicrm-to-new-drupal-instance-upgrade-to-drupal-9))