Drupal 7 upgrade
I would like to upgrade Drupal 7 but not sure what to (9 or 10) and not sure what I need to do with my Civicrm install. Any help would be great. I am in Melbourne, Australia. (relevance being question/answer timing issues)

See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40851/moving-existing-civicrm-to-new-drupal-instance-upgrade-to-drupal-9 which is mostly the same question, but note drupal 9 is end of life now so you want 10 or 11. Additionally php version will need to be 8 to use drupal 10 or 11.

Do you have any content in D7?  In many cases, D7 was just a necessary platform to run Civi on but otherwise is not being used.  If you don't have content to consider then you can just as easily upgrade to WordPress, Backdrop or Standalone - you don't have to continue with Drupal.  (Backdrop is also a good option if you have some D7 content.) Much depends on what you already have and your preferences.

I don't have any other content in D7. I would prefer the easiest option. Would standalone be the best solution? My provider offers Wordpress along Joomla and Drupal. I would love to use standalone.

In that case, Standalone would work for you.  Standalone support is listed as 'beta' in the current 5.80.  See Next steps for Standalone.  Also installing standalone
